# How can I store a number with a leading zero in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to store the number **0.0015** in the database. I have tried **float**, **integer** but I am getting zero not the exact figure I have entered. Is there a datatype which can store such a value?

Comment: What tool do you use  to select data ?

Comment: HOW are you trying to store this number in the database?

Comment: integer will for sure not fit !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'd use `DECIMAL` (aka NUMERIC), with a specified scale and precision, here are the [docs for it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html). `FLOAT` should also work, but you need to be aware of floating point arithmetics quirks, so `DECIMAL` is preferred.

[Here's a dbfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e2ec1184a74903d7d619a89611ad26b1)

If you see your data as 0 then it's either an issue with how you're inserting (maybe importing from a file) or your client rounds it down to 0 and you need to tweak it. As you can see from the dbfiddle above, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

This number (0.0015) is not representable in binary. See the following example in python:

```
Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> x = 0.0015
>>> (x + 1)  - 1
0.0015000000000000568
```

This means that the storing in mysql (or any other language that converts the number to binary) will show up [representation errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems). You can use numeric types that doesn't do any conversion to binary, [like decimal or numeric](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html).